# Compute difference in days between two date variables - Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have two date variables, and I tried to compute the difference in days between them with:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta,datetime

date_format = "%Y/%m/%d"
a = datetime.strptime(df.D1, date_format)
b = datetime.strptime(df.D2, date_format)

df['delta'] = b - a
print delta.days
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series
```

How could I do this? The variables are objects, should I transform them in Datatime64?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're working with `pandas`, you can use `pd.to_datetime` instead of the `datetime` package:

```
# Convert each date column to datetime:
df['D1'] = pd.to_datetime(df.D1,format='%Y/%m/%d')
df['D2'] = pd.to_datetime(df.D2,format='%Y/%m/%d')

# With 2 datetime Series, a simple subtraction will give you a Timedelta column:
df['delta'] = df.D1 - df.D2
```

For example:

```
>>> df
           D1          D2
0  2015/05/18  2014/06/21
1  2015/10/18  2014/08/14

df['D1'] = pd.to_datetime(df.D1,format='%Y/%m/%d')
df['D2'] = pd.to_datetime(df.D2,format='%Y/%m/%d')
df['delta'] = df.D1 - df.D2

>>> df
           D1          D2    delta
0  2015/05/18  2014/06/21 331 days
1  2015/10/18  2014/08/14 430 days
```

Comment: A good idea is to do the conversion *before* your `delta` calculation. You get memory benefits, but more importantly it means any future calculations are vectorised.

Comment: thanks for your help guys. I forgot something: one of the dates has also time (%H%m%s), so when I'm doing the difference I get this:  0 days 15:30:00. How could I get rid of all the rest and just keeping the 0?

Comment: You can do: `df['delta'] = (df.D1 - df.D2).dt.days`, in which case you'll just get an integer representing the number of days. If this answers your questions, please consider accepting it :-)